# deleting dates with difference of two days from today - Doctrine, QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

Hi I have a table with Tasks in my laravel application. I'd like to delete task wchich are odlder than two days from today.

I've writtern function:

```
 public function deleteOldTasks(){

        $results = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
              ->select('cc')->from('\TodoList\Http\Entities\Task', 'cc')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();

        $today = Carbon::today();

        foreach ($results as $result){


            $tempDate =  $result->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $datework = new Carbon($tempDate);
            $diff = $datework->diffInDays($today);
            if($diff >= 2){

                $this->entityManager->persist($result);
            }
         }
        $this->entityManager->flush();


    }
```

This solution dosen't work. Is this correct to delete object in that way? I mean to delete after select with query builder, with using methods persist and flush to remove every simple records from table? This dosen't work in my code. I would be greateful for help. Best regards ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a delete method in your code. Jut before your flush, try to add $this->entityManager->remove($result);